# Postgresql Closing statement takes a long time

Tags: postgresql, go, gorp

In order to add millions of records to a Postgres database with constant memory consumption, I am using a thread pool with several workers as well as a `gorp.Transaction`.

Per million records, the following code is called from different threads about a hundred times, each time handling a batch of 10000 records or so:

```
func batchCopy(p importParams) error {
  copy := pq.CopyIn("entity", "startdate", "value", "expirydate", "accountid")
  stmt, err := p.txn.Prepare(copy)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  for _, r := range p.records {
    _, err := stmt.Exec(
        r.startDate,
        r.value,
        r.expiryDate,
        p.accountId)

    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
  }

  if err := stmt.Close(); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

For some reason, I've noticed that the process tends to be very slow with the `Prepare` and `Close` calls taking very long.

I then tried to reuse the same statement for all of my calls to `batchCopy` and close it after all of them are done. In this case, the `batchCopy` finishes very fast, but when I call `stmt.Close()` - it takes forever.

---

Questions:

- What would be the right way to go about statements? Should I create one per batch or reuse them?
- What is happening in `stmt.Close()` and why does it take so long after many calls to `stmt.Exec`?

Comment: Try to profile where the time is spent. The database? gorp? The application?